# When a quadratic involving three primes is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How do we find all primes $p,q,r$ such that $p^2+q^2+rpq$ is a perfect square ?

with $r=7$ and $p=q$ we have the expression a perfect square

Comment: Have you found any through trials?

Comment: One obvious solution set is $r=2$, $p,q$ any prime, because with $r=2$ you have $p^2+q^2+rpq=(p+q)^2$

Comment: All primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$.

Answer (score -1):

Generally before searching primes need to understand what formula solutions of this equation.
Generally speaking, this equation has a lot of formulas for the solution. Because it is symmetrical.

Write the formula can someone come in handy. the equation:

$Y^2+aXY+X^2=Z^2$

Has a solution:

$X=as^2-2ps$

$Y=p^2-s^2$

$Z=p^2-aps+s^2$

more:

$X=(4a+3a^2)s^2-2(2+a)ps-p^2$

$Y=(a^3-8a-8)s^2+2(a^2-2)ps+ap^2$

$Z=(2a^3+a^2-8a-8)s^2+2(a^2-2)ps-p^2$

more:

$X=(a+4)p^2-2ps$

$Y=3p^2-4ps+s^2$

$Z=(2a+5)p^2-(a+4)ps+s^2$

more:

$X=8s^2-4ps$

$Y=p^2-(4-2a)ps+a(a-4)s^2$

$Z=-p^2+4ps+(a^2-8)s^2$

For the particular case: $Y^2+XY+X^2=Z^2$  You can draw more formulas.

$X=3s^2+2ps$

$Y=p^2+2ps$

$Z=p^2+3ps+3s^2$

more:

$X=3s^2+2ps-p^2$

$Y=p^2+2ps-3s^2$

$Z=p^2+3s^2$

In the equation:  $X^2+aXY+bY^2=Z^2$ there is always a solution and one of them is quite simple.

$X=s^2-bp^2$

$Y=ap^2+2ps$

$Z=bp^2+aps+s^2$

$p,s$ - integers asked us.

Comment: Is this really simpler than brute force? I mean, your formulas are interesting (+1 upvote) but even in the simplest case you have three new parameters $a,p,s$ and you have to check if certain expression are simultaneously prime. With brute force you only have to do one simpler perfect-square-test.

Comment: I showed what numbers are solutions. Clearly, some solutions that can be eliminated. Although I like to write formulas for the solutions of such equations.